# How to compose custom function CNTK

Tags: python, function, segmentation-fault, cntk

I have created a custom function called CustomFunc, following the explanation here: https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/extend.html

If I use it as suggested by the article, it works:

```
model = cntk.user_function(CustomFunc(prev_node))
```

this works fine, the model runs without any problem. My issue is that I want to use this function inside a cntk.layers.Sequential call, and inside a cntk.layers.Recurrence call. To do this, I somehow need to construct the composition of my function with another one, and then put it inside the Sequential or Recurrence call. Right now what I use some placeholder, i.e. I do is:

```
customFunToUse = cntk.user_function(CustomFunc(cntk.placeholder(), otherInputs))
model = cntk.layers.Sequential([cntk.layers.Dense(100), 
                                customFunToUse, 
                                cntk.layers.Recurrence(
                                customFunToUse >> cntk.layers.LSTM(100))])
```

But this doesn't work and raises all kinds of errors: sometimes it's a segfault, in another similar model is a

```
"ValueError: Cannot create an NDArrayView using a view shape '[? x 10]' that has unknown dimensions for any of its axes."
```

Other times instead is a

```
Evaluate: All nodes inside a recurrent loop must have a layout that is identical; mismatch found for nodes ...
```

Note also that my custom function does not alter the input dimensions: given any amount of paramters, it will return the same amount and type. The code is this:

```
class CustomFun(UserFunction):
    def __init__(self, *args, otherStuff, name='CustomFun'):
        super(CustomFun, self).__init__(list(args), name=name)
        self.otherStuff = otherStuff

    def forward(self, arguments, outputs=None, keep_for_backward=None, device=None, as_numpy=True):
        return None,[x/2 for x in arguments]

    def backward(self, state, root_gradients, variables=None, as_numpy=True):
        #it's not important right now, just a test...
        return root_gradient

    def infer_outputs(self):
        #shape, type and dynamic axes of inputs are not changed by this function

        outputVar = [output_variable(self.inputs[idx].shape, self.inputs[idx].dtype,
            self.inputs[idx].dynamic_axes, name='out_quantLayer') for idx in range(len(self.inputs))]
        return outputVar

    def serialize(self):
        return {'otherStuff': self.otherStuff}

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(inputs, name, state):
        return CustomFun(inputs, otherStuff=state['otherStuff'], name=name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be to write something like this

`def my_layer(x):
   @C.Function
   def apply(x):
       return cntk.user_function(CustomFunc(x))
   return apply`

Unfortunately this seems to be causing my Python interpreter to crash. I have opened [github issue 2132](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2132) on this. Will try to update this answer when the issue gets fixed.

**Update:** There was a small typo that we did not catch. There's a resolution at the github issue page.